# how to match columns and calculating percentage using PERL

Tags: perl

I have data like this

```
pop A   B   C   D   E
P1  T/T C/C C/C T/T C/C
P2  A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
1   A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
2   A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
3   A/T A/C A/G A/T A/C
4   T/A T/G T/C T/A T/G
5   G/A G/T G/C G/A G/T
6   C/A C/T C/G C/A C/T
pop A   B   C   D   E
P1  T/T C/C C/C T/T C/C
P2  A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
1   A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
2   A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
3   A/T A/C A/G A/T A/C
4   T/A T/G T/C T/A T/G
5   G/A G/T G/C G/A G/T
6   C/A C/T C/G C/A C/T
```

I want to do the folowwing things on my data

1. I want to convert all `A/A` to `A`, `T/T` to `T`, `C/C` to `C`, `G/G` to `G`, `Z/Z` to `-` and `-/-` to `-` and remaining characters like `A/T`,`G/T`,`C/G`,`T/C` to `H`
2. Now I want to know status from `A` to `E` by comparing `P1` with `P2`, if `P1=P2` then status from `A` to `E` is mono or any one of `P1` or `P2` contains `Z/Z` or `-/-` then status from `A` to `E` is mono else status from `A` to `E` is poly
3. I want to match 1 in `pop` column with `P2` in pop column for `A` to `E`,  if 1 in `pop` column matches to `p2` in `pop` column and its status is poly only then I would like to give 1 otherwise as such, if it is mono I do not want to do anything.
4. Now I will calculate `# 1`s and `# H`'s
5. finally I will calculate `%sim` with this formula `=((#1*2+#H)/((#1+#H)*2))*100`.
6. I want to repeat the same procedure for second set of parents `P1` and `P2`

Expected out will be like this

```
pop A   B   C   D   E   A   B   C   D   E           
P1  POLY    POLY    MONO    MONO    MONO    POLY    POLY    MONO    MONO    MONO    #1's    #H's    %sim
P2  A   G   C   T   C                               
1   A   G   C   T   C   1   1   C   T   C   2   0   100
2   A   G   C   T   C   1   1   C   T   C   2   0   100
3   A   G   C   -   C   H   H   H   H   H   0   5   100
4   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   0   5   50
5   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   0   5   50
6   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   0   5   50
7   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   0   5   50
```

Now I succeed till 1st step but do not know how to proceed further, this is the code i tried till now

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
open(FILE, "<input.txt") || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
my @newlines;
foreach(@lines) {
   $_ =~ s/AA/A/g;
   $_ =~ s/TT/T/g;
   $_ =~ s/GG/G/g;
   $_ =~ s/CC/C/g;
   $_ =~ s/AT/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/AG/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/AC/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/TA/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/TG/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/TC/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/GA/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/GT/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/GC/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/CA/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/CT/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/CG/H/g;
   $_ =~ s/ZZ/-/g;

   push(@newlines,$_);
}
open(FILE, ">input1.txt") || die "File not found";
print FILE @newlines;
close(FILE);
```

Comment: I have no idea of biology but possibly it might help you to be pointed to BioPerl. Then again maybe not, who knows, but i heard if people look for ways to do funny things with huge amounts of As, Ts, Gs, and Cs, they often like to hear about the existence of BioPerl.

Answer (score 1):

This does the replacements and creates the first two lines. I do not understand the rest of the specification (where is the line 7 coming from?)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Data::Dumper;


*ARGV = *DATA{IO} unless @ARGV;

my (@parents, @rows);

sub {
    my $header = <>;
    push @parents, map [ split ' ', <> ], 1, 2;
    push @rows,    map [ split ' ', <> ], 1 .. 6;
}->() for 1, 2;

for (map @$_, @parents, @rows) {
    s= ([ACTG]) / \1 =$1=x;
    s= ([-Z])   / \1 =-=x;
    s= .        / .  =H=x;
}

say join "\t", 'pop', ('A' .. 'E') x 2;

print 'P1';
for my $parent (0, 1) {
    print join "\t", q(), map {
        my $p1 = $parents[ $parent * 2 ][$_];
        my $p2 = $parents[ 1 + $parent * 2 ][$_];
        ($p1 eq $p2 or '-' eq $p1 or '-' eq $p2) ? 'mono' : 'poly';
    } 1 .. 5;
}
print "\n";


__DATA__
pop A   B   C   D   E
P1  T/T C/C C/C T/T C/C
P2  A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
1   A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
2   A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
3   A/T A/C A/G A/T A/C
4   T/A T/G T/C T/A T/G
5   G/A G/T G/C G/A G/T
6   C/A C/T C/G C/A C/T
pop A   B   C   D   E
P1  T/T C/C C/C T/T C/C
P2  A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
1   A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
2   A/A G/G C/C T/T C/C
3   A/T A/C A/G A/T A/C
4   T/A T/G T/C T/A T/G
5   G/A G/T G/C G/A G/T
6   C/A C/T C/G C/A C/T
```

Comment: Dear Choroba,Thank you very much for your reply and i am sorry that 7th line came by mistaque its not part of my data. I exceuted your code and i am getting part of my output like this, pop A B C D E A B C D E
P1 poly poly mono mono mono poly poly mono mono mono
and i am not getting percentages in my output. Thanking you very much for your help onceagain